# Unable to print the following basic pattern

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print This pattern.

1 2 3 4

1 2 3

1 2

1

So I implement this

```
 x = int(input("Enter number of row:\n"))

 for i in range(1,x+1):

     for j in range(1,x+1):

         print(j,end=" ")

     print()
```

but I don't get as showed in question
I know that no. of column have to decreased by one but how ever I can not managed to do that.
please tell me what I have to do in order to solve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i would do it:

```
x = int(input("Enter number of row:\n"))
for i in range(1,x+1):
    print(*range(1,x+1))
    x-=1
```

Comment: thanks for you help. I got the answer. I am a learn also a beginner so i don't know what '*' doing here. Please tell me no one gonna tell me this particularly.